# SSIS Date dataype conversion

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ssis

I was trying to create two variables of type date in my SSIS package. I am passing a datetime(as there is no chance of taking a direct date type) parameter to the package. The two date variables are using this parameter and they are being created using expressions.

Let the parameter be **Period**. The two variables are **Var1** and **Var2**.

Now I am trying to do the following tasks

Period is of type DateTime. VAR1 is of type Date.  VAR2 must be of type Date.

```
 Period = 2016-01-01 00.00.000
 VAR1 = (DT_DBDATE)(Period)
 VAR2 = DATEADD("dd" , -1,  DATEADD( "mm", 1, VAR1  ) )
```

I was getting data type errors when i am trying to assign the VAR2 this value. Even Tried changing the dat type of VAR1. I tried object type also.

Can anyone please help me in solving this. VAR1 and VAR2 must be of type DT_DATE.  What type of conversions/changes can be made to get it done.

Comment: The variable VAR2 must be of type DT_DBDATE. I have no option other than Datetime to declare the variables when I am creating. When I am using Object type and assigning expression to that, it automatically changes to Datetime. When using DateTime, I cant convert it to DT_DBDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the converted period to `VAR1` but continue to use `period` in your `dateadd` function.

Try it like this

```
 Period = 2016-01-01 00.00.000
 VAR1 = (DT_DATE)(Period)
 VAR2 = (DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("dd" , -1,  DATEADD( "mm", 1, VAR1  ) )
```

Comment: I am Sorry. The variable    VAR2     must be of type    DT_DBDATE    . So, I tried the same what you have given. But again got type conversion error What data type can be used and and to which type that variable must be assigned. I have no option other than Datetime to declare the variables when I am creating. When I am using Object type and assigning expression to that, it automatically changes to Datetime.

Comment: That's not what your question stated, try my edit and see if it works, I have no access to the test environment at the momen

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way to convert dates in SSIS. I usually go to SUBSTRING. It may not be beautiful, but it is effective.

`Period = 2016-01-01 00.00.000
VAR1 = (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(Period),1,10)
VAR2 = (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(DATEADD("dd" , -1, DATEADD( "mm", 1, [period])),1,10))`

might need to throw a cast (DT_WSTR,20) in there to substring.